# Run php script artisan opcache:optimize after php7.2-fpm start or restart

Tags: ubuntu, php, debian, php-fpm, init.d

I want to run

```
php /path/to/artisan opcache:optimize
```

to build `laravel` cache after `php7.2-fpm` start or after restart.
I have tried to insert it on `/etc/init.d/php7.2-fpm` in `do_start()` method but failed the code didn't execute.

please any idea? thanks

Comment: You are supposed to do this when you deploy a new version of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by editing `/lib/systemd/system/php7.2-fpm.service`

i add `ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/php /path/to/artisan opcache:optimize`
and then reload daemon

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```